# JQuery Delete and Consolidate array

Tags: jquery, arrays, dynamic-tables

So I have a dynamic table on my page that the user can add, edit and delete entries. This is my jquery code for removing a row from the table:

```
$("#table").on("click", "button", function() {
       $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
       num_rows--;
       delete fname_new[num_row];
       delete lname_new[num_row];
       delete phone_new[num_row];
       delete email_new[num_row];
       delete ethnicity_new[num_row];
    });
```

But the problem is, lets say the fname_new array has 4 entries from 4 rows. So fname_new will contain the first name data each row so it'll look like this:

```
[row0,row1,row2,row3]
```

But let's say the user deletes row 2, i took care of the delete from the above code but then the fname_new array looks like this:

```
[row0, ,row2,row3]
```

but I want to consolidate it and make it look like this:

```
[row0,row2,row3]
```

How do I do that? I tried using grep but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: basic array manipulation... read: http://www.elated.com/articles/manipulating-javascript-arrays/

Comment: Not directly related to deleting/splicing, but rather than maintaining five separate arrays, one for each field, I'd use one array where each element is an object with a property for each field. (Then to delete you only have to update one array.)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your "delete" statements with this, assuming `num_row` is zero-based.

```
  fname_new.splice(num_row, 1);
  lname_new.splice(num_row, 1);
  phone_new.splice(num_row, 1);
  email_new.splice(num_row, 1);
  ethnicity_new.splice(num_row, 1);
```